# How to configure a custom URL for WAMP server

Tags: localhost, ip, wampserver

I'm trying to set up a local install of a PHP application. Everything works in WAMP server except one thing. The application is set up so that different URL's can be configured to access different parts with different user permissions. So to emulate this on the local server I need to use a custom URL. These are configured in the application database. Here I have set up site.loc as the secondary URL in the database. I tried adding the following line to my hosts file (Windows 10):

127.0.0.1 site.loc

I've added this to httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site.loc
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also made sure this is uncommented in httpd.conf Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

But it just tells me the site can't be reached. I'm assuming that there is nothing wrong with the application itself, but that the problem is in the routing.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Create 1 or more Virtual Hosts, [this answer should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990618/2310830)

Comment: I just tried that and updated the question to reflect.

Comment: try adding `::1 site.loc` in the hosts file as well

Comment: And change `Order allow,deny & Allow from all` to `Require local`

Comment: ___NOTE___ You are not supposed to put any of your code in the `wamp\www` folder. You should have put your site code in either a subfolder like `wamp/www/site.loc` or a completely seperate folder somewhere on your disk

Comment: Any reason why you are using the 32 bit wampserver rather than the 64 bit? Or did you just overwrite the default folder name

Answer (score 0):

This solution was this: In httpd.conf I had this line

```
Listen 0.0.0.:8080
```

So I changed the virtual host to 8080

Then I was able to open the site by typing:

http://site.loc:8080